# Item(s) are added into cart, but the total is not updating as per the item(s) added. If I increment/decrement the quantity the total is being updated

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, e-commerce

I have been working on a nodeJs | Express | MySQL - Ecommerce website with connection to MySQL. In the project, I have developed the code to add the product into the cart by redirecting the user into the "cart.ejs" page. But if one product is added the subtotal is being updated instantly but the grand total is displaying "0". If i increase the product quantity or decrease the product quantity then the loop is being executed and the grand total is being displayed. Please check the code and provide me with some help in this situation. Thanks in advance.

In the below images, the calculateTotal is the function which should calculate the totals for the products added into the cart page. Currently this is only executing if I do some modifications in the page such as increasing the product quantity. But this should be executed immediately when the product is added into the cart, that is how an e-commerce website works right?

In the screenshot of the browser window, you can see the subtotal is being displayed at the same instance when the product is added into the cart, but the total is still being "0".

This is my HTML Code::

```
<section id="cart">
```

Proceed to Checkout
    You have succesfully placed your item(s) into the cart, 
Please verify the products you want before heading over to the checkout page.
  
    
    
      
        
          #
          Product
          Description
          Quantity
          Sub Total

```
  <% cart.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <tr>
    <th>PAC</th>
    <td>
      <div class="product_info">
        <img src="images/products/<%= item.image %>" style="height: 100px; width:100px"> 
         <td><p style="font-weight: bold;"><%= item.name %></p>

          <!-- To display the sale price -->
          <% if(item.sale_price) { %>
            <small>£<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><%= item.sale_price %></span></small>
            <% } else { %>
          <small>£<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><%= item.price %></span></small>
          <% } %>
          <br/><br/>
          <form method="post" action="/remove_product">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= item.id %>">
            <input type="submit" name="remove_btn" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" value="Delete">
          </form>
        
      </div>
    </td>
</td>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="/edit_product_quantity">

        <input type="hidden" value="<%= item.id %>" name="id">
        <input type="submit" value="-" class="edit-btn text-center" name="decrease_product_quantity">
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<%= item.quantity %>" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" readonly>
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="edit-btn text-center" name="increase_product_quantity">
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!-- To display the subtotal in the table if the item has sale_price (or) without the sale_price -->
        <% if(item.sale_price) { %>
      <p>£<span class="product-price" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><%= item.sale_price * item.quantity %></span></p>
        <% } else { %>
         <p>£<span class="product-price" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><%= item.price * item.quantity %></span></p>
        <% } %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% }) %>
</table><br/>
```

Total
              £
              (incl. of all taxes)
              Go to Homepage
              Proceed to Checkout

This is my calculateTotal function in app.js code ::

```
function calculateTotal(cart,req){
total = 0;
for (let i=0; i<cart.length; i++) {
    //If we are offering a discounted price so we need to use the sale_price
    if (cart[i].sale_price){
        total = total + (cart[i].sale_price * cart[i].quantity);
    } else {
        total = total + (cart[i].price * cart[i].quantity)
    }
}

req.session.total = total;
return total;
```

}

This is my addToCart function:

```
app.post("/add_to_cart", function(req,res){
let id = req.body.id;
let name = req.body.name;
let price = req.body.price;
let sale_price = req.body.sale_price;
let quantity = req.body.quantity;
let image = req.body.image;
let product = {id:id, name:name, price:price, sale_price:sale_price, quantity:quantity, image:image};

if (req.session.cart){
    let cart = req.session.cart;

    if(!isProductInCart(cart,id)){
        cart.push(product);
    }
} else {
    req.session.cart = [product];
    let cart = req.session.cart;
}
```

[This is the liveserver in vs code in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvstt.png)

Please do help! Thanks

Comment: Is the cart array filled if you log the value before the calculateTotal function in your post req?

Comment: Always add code as text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BertVanHecke I think that is the problem, I have initialised the total as 0, now when the product is added into cart the calculateTotal function is taking the 0 as the input and returning the total. The function is not proceeding further into the for loop unless and until the quantity of the product is changed. Can you please help me with this problem

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I am sorry, This is my first post in the stack overflow. Currently getting used to the functions available. Now I have updated the post, can you please refer to the code and help me with a solution. Thanks